# Obtaining residual variance from glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet

I am working with `glmnet` and I'd like to see how we can obtain a residual variance for a given penalty parameter in prediction. I use `glmnet`'s `QuickStartExample` example ([here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/glmnet_beta.html#cmp)) and focus on L1 penalty with a given `lambda`. My code is as follows:

```
require(glmnet)
data(QuickStartExample)
fit <- glmnet(x, y, intercept = F, standardize = F, thresh = 1e-20, alpha = 1)
```

Following, I extracted coefficient vector using `predict` function to get the exact solution for 25th lambda as follows:

```
beta_glmnet = as.matrix(predict(fit, s = fit$lambda[25]/(2*dim(x)[1]), type = "coefficients", exact = T)[-1,])
```

My question is how we can obtain an estimate (preferably an unbiased one) of residual variance for the above model. My initial thought was `fit$dev.ratio[25]/fit$df[25]`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In my understanding it is in deviance function of glmnet

```
data.table(l=fit$lambda, d=deviance(fit))[abs(l-reg.lambda) == min(abs(l-reg.lambda))]$d[1]
```

Comment: Is the deviance the residual _variance_ or the square root thereof?

Comment: never mind: experiments indicate it is indeed variance, as it scales with $y$ _squared_. That is, running a `glmnet` fit twice, once with $y$, once with $10y$ results in deviances that are 100x bigger.

Comment: ahh, but you must adjust for the number of observations, as deviance is like a raw sum of squares.